# Does mlock prevent the page from appearing in a core dump?

Tags: memory-management, embedded-linux, coredump

I have a process with some sensitive memory which must never be written to disk.

I also have a requirement that I need core dumps to satisfy first-time data capture requirements of my client.

Does locking a page using mlock() prevent the page from appearing in a core dump?

Note, this is an embedded system and we don't actually have any swap space.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from `man 2 madvise`:

> The  madvise()  system  call  advises the kernel about how to handle
>   paging input/output in the address range beginning at address addr and
>   with size length bytes. It allows an application to tell the kernel
>   how it expects to use some mapped or shared memory areas, so that the
>   kernel  can choose appropriate read-ahead and caching techniques. 
>   This call does not influence the semantics of the application (except
>   in the case of MADV_DONTNEED), but may influence its performance. The
>   kernel is free to ignore the advice.

Particularly check the option `MADV_DONTDUMP` :

> Exclude from a core dump those pages in the range specified by addr
>   and length. This is useful in applications that have large areas of
>   memory that are known not to be useful in a core dump.  The effect of
>   MADV_DONTDUMP takes precedence over the bit mask that is set via the
>   /proc/PID/coredump_filter file (see core(5)).